# DALI DT8 tunable white control - novice in need of help!

Tags: temperature, lighting, dali, colour, white

Completely new to DALI, and I need to control a tunable white luminaire.
I have a Hasseb USB to DALI interface (http://www.hasseb.fi/shop2/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=50), which enables me to adjust the brightness and such, but I am completely at a loss when it comes to the colour temperature. They've told me that it fully supports DALI 2. I've consulted the DS/EN 62386-209 standard for answers, but to no avail.
Is the colour temperature linked to some specific scene, should it be controllable using an extra parameter with "Direct ARC power control" or is it specific to the manufacturer of the luminaire (no, no, no, impossible, right?)? Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 1):

In the gear, colours can be linked to scenes or can be set independently. For example to set the colour temperature (assuming auto activate is true), you would need to send the following sequence of commands:

```
Command 257 Set DTR to the LSB of the Mirek value you want
Command 273 Set DTR1 to the MSB of the Mirek value you want
Command 272 Enable Device Type, with value 8 (for type 209 gear)
Command 231 Set Temporary Colour Temperature Tc, addressed to the gear.
```

Of these, only command 231 is addressed, the rest are processed by all the gear on the bus. So to select between applying this to all (broadcast), group or short address of an individual gear, you set the address bits in command 231.

I had a quick look at the Hasseb software and it doesn't support the complete command set needed for all device types so you will have to make changes to the source code or use the python library, or another tool.