# DALI 209 DT8 RGB color commands

Tags: rgb, lighting, dali

I know how to send DALI comands to change the temperature.
It is done by sending to following commands:

```
#257 DAT0 -> load DAT0 into the LSB Temporary register
#273 DAT1 -> load DAT1 into the MSB Temporary register
#272 8 -> enable device type 8
#231 addressed to the gear -> Apply Temporary register as Colour Temperature
```

I also know that the LSB and MSB should be mirek values simply coded as uint16. so it is trivial to compute the DAT0 and DAT1 knowing the desired temperature.

I also know that there are commands to set the X and Y coordinate. So I try to do the following:

```
#257 DAT2 -> load DAT2 into the LSB Temporary register
#273 DAT3 -> load DAT3 into the MSB Temporary register
#272 8 -> enable device type 8
#224 addressed to the gear -> Apply Temporary register as X coordinate
#257 DAT4 -> load DAT4 into the LSB Temporary register
#273 DAT5 -> load DAT5 into the MSB Temporary register
#272 8 -> enable device type 8
#225 addressed to the gear -> Apply Temporary register as Y coordinate
#272 8 -> enable device type 8
#226 addressed to the gear -> 'Activate' the X/Y color point...
```

I have two questions.

1. How do I compute DALI X and Y 16 bit values given the floating point x y of the desired color? i.e. x/y in CIE 1960 color space to DALI X and Y
2. How to correctly set the X and Y coordinate to DT8 DALI devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. How do I compute DALI X and Y 16 bit values given the floating point x y of the desired color? i.e. x/y in CIE 1960 color space to DALI X and Y

My copy of IEC 62386-209:2011 says that for both commands 224 (`SET TEMPORARY x-COORDINATE`) and 225 (`SET TEMPORARY y-COORDINATE`), *"the value is expressed in units of 1/65536"*, and that the maximum x-/y-coordinate value is `0.99997`. Then, in Table 8, *Declaration of variables*, it says that these variables have a range of 0-65534, and 65535 corresponds to `MASK`. Since 65534/65536 is roughly 0.999969482421875, this cross-checks. So it's really just `max(min(round(your_float * 65536), 65534), 0)`.

> 2. How to correctly set the X and Y coordinate to DT8 DALI devices?

I've only worked with CCT devices, but this is described in Table 15, *Command versus the DTR, DTR1 and DTR2 cross-reference*. For the X-coordinate, you convert your floating point to a 16-bit integer as shown above, then you store its LSB into the `DTR` register and its MSB into the `DTR1` register, and then you invoke command `224`. For the Y-coordinate, you do the same, but issue command `225`. It's essentially the same as in [this answer for CCT DT8](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/605066/162114) (which shows you the relevant part of the table I mentioned), except that you send 224 or 225 instead of `231`.

Comment: Which color space does DALI use? I can only find one graph with x and y that makes sense: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space#/media/File:CIE1931xy_blank.svg
But there are many graphs with different scales...

Comment: Warning: anything related to color spaces, color perception and colorimetry in general is about 666× more complicated than it appears on a first sight. That said, my copy of the standard says `Figure 1 – The CIE color space chromaticity diagram, 1931 Cambridge University Press`, and the picture looks pretty much like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space#/media/File:CIE-1931_diagram_in_LAB_space.svg . What problem are you solving, btw?

Comment: I was shocked that a simple usb/dali converter can cost several hundreds of dollars. So I built my own and am trying to drive some cheap chinese LEDS. Turns out that the leads on the LEDs are not labled correctly, so even after managing to send the correct commands, the color was somehow incorrect until I connected the LED strip correctly.